# Script doesn't produce any output after being converted to Win executable

Tags: python, window, exe, python-3.6

I have a python (3.6) script prints the output using `print()` command:

```
print(convert_size(logsize))
```

Then I converted the script to .exe using cx_Freeze 5.0.1. When it does work from IDLE and prints the output, launching .exe file with double-click, or as Administrator, or executing it from cmd as Administrator doesn't produce any output at all: http://prnt.sc/emz5m4

I have tried to add `input()` at the end of the script and then re-compile the file to .exe, which supposed to "stop" window from closing but it still closes.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the recompiled exe?

Comment: To see the output you will have to run it from the command-line. Windows program don't have a `stdout` by default (which is where `print()` output is sent).

Comment: @Ashish yes, 100% sure.
martineau right but it still cannot be executed in the cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the pyinstaller has been launched from 3.6 location since I had it installed for 2.7 and 3.6. Once the correct location (C:\Python27\Scripts) has been pointed to, the script has been compiled successfully!

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen to you only when compiling this script, or also with other scripts?

If you can't manage to get outputs into a console with cx_Freeze, maybe you can try compiling with pyinstaller.  Specifically, the options '--console' or '--noconsole' will give you control over whether a console opens or not to see the outputs.  It has worked fine for me.

https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html

Comment: none of the scripts are working. I have tried  (version 3.2.1) pyinstaller script.py but it threw an error: IndexError: tuple index out of range
I checked it appeared it doesn't support Python 3.6 they I used 2.7 Python for this script but it appeared not to be working as well (same error)